# Telegram - 401 AUTH_KEY_UNREGISTERED

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

I am trying to get the Telegram API working by saving the StringSession in a database and then using it to access the channels on my telegram app.

But with the following codes, I am facing the issue around 401 - Unregistered Auth Key.

Is there anyway to verify that the Auth key is registered? Or is there anything wrong with the codes?

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

```
 const apiId = result.apiId;
        const apiHash = result.apiHash;
        const _stringSession = new telegramStringSession.StringSession(result.stringSession);
        const client = new telegramClient.TelegramClient(_stringSession, apiId, apiHash, {
            connectionRetries: 3,
        });
        
        await client.connect();
        const dialogs = await client.getDialogs(new iterDialogs(this, {
            limit: 100
        }));
```

Comment: Make sure you are using correct API ID and Hash